# why when i run mysql.exe (which is located in xampp/mysql/bin) only appears for a moment then (the program) disappears?

Tags: mysql, database, xampp

why when i run mysql.exe which is located in

> `C:xampp\mysql\bin`

, the program only appears for a moment then disappear.
the program that should appear contains(`....... MariaDb`)
I've tried running the program as administrator.
And my MySQL program can run when i run it on XAMPP control panel

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql.html

Comment: Run it from command line `cmd` and the window won't close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are NOT supposed to double click on it and expect a login window to maigically pop up. Instead, open a CMD terminal and launch it through command-line interface. Before trying the command, it would be better to make sure the path `C:\xampp\mysql\bin` is registered in the `PATH` system variable.Then try this in CMD:

```
mysql -u root -p
```